# Excel zip packaging using System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, mono, zip, system.io.compression

I'm creating an excel file (xlsx) based on Office Open XML. This is how my code looks like.

```
        string basePath = Util.GetAppDirectoryPath ();
        string excelDirectory = Path.Combine (basePath, "temp", "xlsx");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (excelDirectory);

        StreamWriter swContentType;
        using (swContentType = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (excelDirectory, "[Content_Types].xml"))) {
            swContentType.Write (CONTENT_TYPES);
            swContentType.Flush ();
        }

        string docPropsDirectory = Path.Combine (excelDirectory, "docProps");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (docPropsDirectory);

        StreamWriter swApp;
        using (swApp = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (docPropsDirectory, "app.xml"))) {
            swApp.Write (APPXML);
            swApp.Flush ();
        }

        StreamWriter swCore;
        using (swCore = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (docPropsDirectory, "core.xml"))) {
            swCore.Write (COREXML);
            swCore.Flush ();
        }

        string xlDirectory = Path.Combine (excelDirectory, "xl");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (xlDirectory);

        FileStream fsSharedStrings;
        using (fsSharedStrings = System.IO.File.Create (Path.Combine (xlDirectory, "sharedStrings.xml"))) {
            WriteStringCache (fsSharedStrings);
        }

        StreamWriter swStyles;
        using (swStyles = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (xlDirectory, "styles.xml"))) {
            WriteStyles (swStyles);
        }

        StreamWriter swWorkbook;
        using (swWorkbook = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (xlDirectory, "workbook.xml"))) {
            WriteWorkbook (swWorkbook);
        }

        string xlThemeDirectory = Path.Combine (xlDirectory, "theme");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (xlThemeDirectory);

        StreamWriter swTheme;
        using (swTheme = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (xlThemeDirectory, "theme1.xml"))) {
            WriteTheme (swTheme);
        }

        string xlWorksheetsDirectory = Path.Combine (xlDirectory, "worksheets");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (xlWorksheetsDirectory);

        FileStream fsWorksheets;
        if (_Sheets.Count == 0) {   // output an empty work sheet
            using (fsWorksheets = System.IO.File.Create (Path.Combine (xlWorksheetsDirectory, "sheet1.xml"))) {
                WriteEmptyWorksheet (fsWorksheets);
            }
        } else {// output the spreadsheets
            foreach (SheetInfo sinfo in _Sheets) {
                string sname = string.Format ("{0}.xml", sinfo.Name);
                using (fsWorksheets = System.IO.File.Create (Path.Combine (xlWorksheetsDirectory, sname))) {
                    WriteData (fsWorksheets, sinfo.Grid, sinfo.MergeCells); // here's where the meat of the data goes
                }

            }
        }

        string rels = Path.Combine (xlDirectory, "_rels");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (rels);

        StreamWriter swWorkbookRels;
        using (swWorkbookRels = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (rels, "workbook.xml.rels"))) {
            WriteWorkbookRels (swWorkbookRels);
        }

        string relsDirectory = Path.Combine (excelDirectory, "_rels");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (relsDirectory);

        StreamWriter swRels;
        using (swRels = System.IO.File.CreateText (Path.Combine (relsDirectory, ".rels"))) {
            swRels.Write (RELS_RELS);
            swRels.Flush ();
        }

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(excelDirectory, Path.Combine(basePath, "temp", "temp.xlsx"), CompressionLevel.Optimal, false);
```

I'm creating all the directories and write all the metadata that is neccesary. The Problem is that if I use ZipFile from System.IO.Compression to zip the created directory (excelDirectory) the file would be corrupted, but if I compress the directory using Arhive Manager or 7Zip the file would be good. What can be the problem ?

I'm using Linux Mint. Monodevelop. Mono.

Comment: What means "corrupted"? if you rename it to .zip can you open the file? and if yes, the structure created is exactly the same as the one created with 7zip?

Comment: Corrupted means that LibreOffice or Microsoft Office can't open it. Yes, if I rename it to .zip I can extract it and the structure is the same as it was created. And if I compress again all the folders from extracted zip the file would be good.

Comment: If you rename it to zip and you can extract it, then it is not corrupted. What happens is that you're not following the spec that LO/MO may need.

Comment: Test it with MS.NET on Windows (i.e. Visual Studio Community), and if it works there, then it must be a Mono bug (in this case, upgrade your Mono version)